# Averaging numeric values of all files for three different folders using Python

Tags: python, csv, operating-system

I am trying to average the numeric values in the file for each `var`. It works fine for `var_values=1.0` but it is not working for `var_values=5.0,10.0`. I present the current output. The expected output should have numeric values for `var_values=5.0,10.0` as each file in the respective folders have non-zero values.

```
import os
import csv

NFILES = 501
Folder_name = '4_1012_nodes_var_1_K_1e3_Cb_1e-3_D_1e-10'

K = 1e3
Cb = 1e-3
DiffCoeff = 1e-10
mean_radii = 50.0
var_values = [1.0, 5.0, 10.0]
Distribution = 'ND'

for var in var_values:
    numeric_values = []  # Reset the list for each var iteration
    file_count = 0  # Counter for the number of files processed

    for i in range(1, NFILES):
        folder_path = rf"D:\Users\debanikb\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder_name}\{i}\Time_{mean_radii}_{var}{Distribution}_{K}_{Cb}_{DiffCoeff}.csv"

        if os.path.isfile(folder_path):
            with open(folder_path, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                row_values = []
                for row in reader:
                    for value in row:
                        try:
                            numeric_value = float(value)
                            row_values.append(numeric_value)
                        except ValueError:
                            pass
                if row_values:
                    numeric_values.extend(row_values)
                file_count += 1

    if file_count > 0:
        average = sum(numeric_values) / len(numeric_values)
        print(f"Average of numeric values for var={var}:", average)
        print(f"Number of files averaged for var={var}:", file_count)
    else:
        print(f"No numeric values found for var={var}.")
```

The data format of the files look like

[image]

The current output is

```
Average of numeric values for var=1.0: 1.4373770078023274
Number of files averaged for var=1.0: 34
No numeric values found for var=5.0.
No numeric values found for var=10.0.
```

Comment: Hi Nick! Would you be able to post a few lines of one of the files, to give me an idea what it looks like? thanks!

Comment: Have you considered or would you be open to using Pandas or Dask?

Comment: I have presented the data form and I am open to using Pandas or Dask.

Comment: The way you're choosing the files to work with looks very strange. It seems that you can process no more than 1,500 files. What if there are more than that number of files? What do the files look like? We know they're CSV but an example of specific values/layout would be very helpful. From what you've shown it looks like there's only ever 1 row with one column. Surely not!

Comment: I have presented a snapshot of the ```csv``` file.

Comment: @KeplerNick123 Please confirm that each CSV file contains a header line and one other row and that the row contains just one value. That's what your sample shows but if that's the case then there's an awful lot of redundant code in your question

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: If your CSV files only have one value in them then I think Pandas is overkill.  @DarkKnight's solution is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the very simple nature of the file content, there's no real need for the CSV module.

Just do this:

```
import os

Folder_name = '4_1012_nodes_var_1_K_1e3_Cb_1e-3_D_1e-10'
K = 1e3
Cb = 1e-3
DiffCoeff = 1e-10
mean_radii = 50.0
var_values = [1.0, 5.0, 10.0]
Distribution = 'ND'
NFILES = 500
DIR = f'D:\\Users\\debanikb\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Surfactant A-D\\{Folder_name}'

results = {}
file_count = {}

for i in range(1, NFILES+1):
    if os.path.isdir(_dir := os.path.join(DIR, str(i))):
        for var in var_values:
            path = os.path.join(_dir, f'Time_{mean_radii}_{var}{Distribution}_{K}_{Cb}_{DiffCoeff}.csv')
            try:
                with open(path) as file:
                    file_count[var] = file_count.get(var, 0) + 1
                    results.setdefault(var, []).append(file.readlines()[1])
            except Exception:
                pass
```

At this point the dictionaries *results* and *file_count* will have all the information you need to proceed

```
for var in var_values:
    if (times := results.get(var)):
        mean = sum(map(float, times)) / len(times)
        print(f'Average of numeric values for var={var}: {mean}')
        print(f'Number of files averaged for var={var}: {file_count[var]}')
    else:
        print(f'No numeric values found for var={var}')
```